# Asp.net throwing an exception when using label ID and AssociatedControlID name different using C#

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, exception

In asp.net I am using the label field in which I am keeping ID and  AssociatedControlID same then its not throwing any exception

```
   <asp:Label ID="Username" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Username">Username:</asp:Label>
```

But when I am using ID and AssociatedControlID differently then I am getting an exception

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Username">Username:</asp:Label>
```

the exception I am getting is

Unable to find control with id 'Username' that is associated with the Label 'lblUsername'

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you associate a label to another control like a `TextBox`.

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="myTextBox">Username:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
```

Since you try to associate it to some control with id `Username` in the second example I can guess that you don't have another control with id `Username`. That is why you're getting the exception.